# Rails 4 mailers with gmail smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to use the Mailer of Rails 4 with the Gmail's smtp configuration
In my development file i set:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => "mymail@gmail.com",
      :password             => "mygmailpassword",
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

but i don't recive any mails.
This is the output of the terminal:

```
To: antonioni.giovanni9@gmail.com
Message-ID: <55ffb56da9e91_aa929362303435c@pc-rails.mail>
Subject: Conferma ordine
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_55ffb56da807b_aa92936230342e1";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_55ffb56da807b_aa92936230342e1
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

so my application try to send an email but this not appear on my gmail dashboard.
Any idea for resolve this trouble?

Comment: Try make `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` to true in your development.rb file `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and see actual errors. Your code seems perfect.

Comment: it return me this error: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required

Comment: 2 stepe verification?

Comment: Yes you need to provide verification from gmail. There is 2 step varigication needed to send email using smtp from gmail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail smtp service need an APP PASSWORD for send a mail from a gmail account (for more info visit this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)). After generating the password you must change the configuration of the development file:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => "mymail@gmail.com",
      :password             => "GENERATEDPASSWORD",
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

And then restart the server.
For catching the error i've set: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` (Thanks Dipak for the tip)

Comment: Some time you may also get 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required then https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha link will solve access issue.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change this: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps